# Moodle Error "you dont have permission to view course here."

Tags: moodle

I am working as a teacher in college. I have installed moodle 3.7+ with php7.1.29 on our server. Initially system worked well now there are almost 800 courses and 3000 users registered to system. but now every user getting error message saying "you dont have permission to view course here." this error is show till user refreshes the page 2-3 times and after refreshing page it show course. I have attached screenshot here....can anyone please help me with the problem.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try purging the caches:

```
/path/to/php /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/purge_caches.php
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you don't have any hidden categories.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that string in Moodle 3.7. It might be a plugin causing this.

If you are able to, can you go to Site admin > Development > Debugging

or direct to /admin/settings.php?section=debugging

and enable `debugstringids`

Then go to the course and add &strings=1 to the end of the url

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Language_customisation#Finding_the_component_and_string_identifier

This will display the source of the string

Answer (score 0):

If administrators can open the course just fine, but other users is having this issue: check the course and category management, make sure the course in question is not inside a hidden category, or the top /parent category is hidden.